# Elasticsearch custom analyser migration from ES 1.x to ES 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-analyzers, elasticsearch1.3.2

Requirement:

Search for documents that contains the given phrase (which has the words in the phrase in order).

It's working fine in the setup where the ES 1.x is used. I'm trying to update the ES version to 7.x. Getting issues when updating the queries to be comply with ES 7.x version, it returns the documents which contain a part of the given phrase.

The query used against ES 1.x:

```json
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "or": {
                "filters": [
                  {
                    "query": {
                      "match": {
                        "document": {
                          "query": "dream comes true",
                          "type": "phrase",
                          "operator": "AND"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query used in the migrated environment:

```json
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "document": {
                    "query": "dream comes true"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The later one gives even the partial phrase present in the document. I have checked the analyser configurations.

Both analysers (in 1.x and 7.x uses):
`html_strip` as char_filter and `uax_url_email` tokenizer. Other filters are same except,the 1.x setup has `standard` filter which is removed in 7.x.

Even though the analyser configuration is same, there is difference in the results when analysing the phrase using http://xxxx:9200/xxxx/_analyze:

For 1.x:

```json
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "analyzer",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 15,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "docs_analyzer",
            "start_offset": 19,
            "end_offset": 35,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "text",
            "start_offset": 43,
            "end_offset": 47,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "dreams",
            "start_offset": 51,
            "end_offset": 57,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "comes",
            "start_offset": 58,
            "end_offset": 63,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "token": "true",
            "start_offset": 64,
            "end_offset": 68,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

For 7.x:

```json
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "dream",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "shingle",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "come",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "shingle",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "dream",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "shingle",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "come",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "shingle",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "true",
            "start_offset": 13,
            "end_offset": 17,
            "type": "shingle",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "come",
            "start_offset": 13,
            "end_offset": 13,
            "type": "shingle",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "true",
            "start_offset": 13,
            "end_offset": 17,
            "type": "shingle",
            "position": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

**Update**

1.x:

Index mapping

```
"document": { 
    "type": "string",
    "boost": 8,
    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
    "analyzer": "docs_analyzer",
    "similarity": "BM25"
}
```

Analyzer:

```
"docs_analyzer": {  
  "type": "custom",
  "char_filter": "html_strip",
  "filter": [  
      "standard",
      "asciifolding",
      "word_delimiter",
      "lowercase",
      "stop_filter",
      "kstem"
],
   "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
}
```

7.x

```
"document": { 
   "type": "text",
   "boost": 8,
   "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
   "analyzer": "docs_analyzer",
   "similarity": "BM25"
}
```

```
"docs_analyzer": { 
     "filter": [  
         "asciifolding",
         "word_delimiter_graph",
         "lowercase",
         "stop_filter",
         "kstem"
  ],
   "char_filter": "html_strip",
   "type": "custom",
   "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
            }
```

Comment: Can you add the index mapping you had for the `document` field as well as the analyzer settings, for both 1.x and 7x, so we can compare apples to apples?

Comment: @Val Updated question